# Django model association, users, profiles and idea model

Tags: django-models, django-templates

I have an app that makes use of 'django-registration' a custom built model named 'idea' and also a 'userprofile'

Now the Idea class looks as follows

> class Idea(models.Model):
>        title = ...
>        user = models.ForeignKey(User)

The User class is Django's Auth User system.

And the UserProfile looks as follow.

> class UserProfile(ImageModel):
>       user = models.ForeignKey(User)
>       image = models.ImageField(.....)

Now lets say in my frontpage I want to display all Idea and have the user and his "avatar" to display.

How do I associate all three models without having to render it through the Context.

> {% for ideas in idea %}
>       {{ idea.user.get_full_name }} just posted an idea with the name of {{ idea.title }}
>   {% endofr %}

Now I would like to display the users profile pic in this too.

Best I can come up with is

> {% for userprofile in idea.user_set.all %}
>   img src="{{ userprofile.image }}"
>       {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way in the long run is to register an inclusion tag so you can reuse this with any model.

Answer (score 0):

The idea instance has a user, by way of the ForeignKey. On user instances, you have a `get_profile` method that returns the related profile for this user.

So you could do something like this (untested):

```
{% for idea in ideas %}
  {{ idea.user.get_full_name }} <img src="{{ idea.user.get_profile.image }}"/> just posted an idea with the name {{ idea.title }}
{% endfor %}
```